# Horizontal ListView not showing in release mode working fine in debug mode in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

'''

```
Container(
                    //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: getContracts(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Center(
                              child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                    Color(AppColors.progressBarcolor),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                child: const Text('Fatching Vehicles...'),
                              )
                            ],
                          ));
                        } else {
                          return SizedBox(
                              height: 90,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                //physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                //shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      converages(
                                          snapshot.data[index].coverages);
                                      setState(() {
                                        _selectedIndex = index;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 220,
                                      height: 70,
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 5, left: 20),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: _selectedIndex == index
                                            ? Color(AppColors.primaryBlueColor)
                                            : Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(15)),
                                      ),

                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5),
                                      child: Expanded(
                                        child: Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                height: 64,
                                                width: 64,
                                                //margin:
                                                //    const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.all(
                                                            Radius.circular(
                                                                10)),
                                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                                      image: AssetImage(
                                                          "lib/Assets/Images/car.png"),
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    )),
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Container(
                                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      left: 10),
                                                  child: Center(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: Align(
                                                            alignment: Alignment
                                                                .bottomLeft,
                                                            child: Container(
                                                              padding:
                                                                  const EdgeInsets
                                                                      .all(0),
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                "${snapshot.data[index].make}  ${snapshot.data[index].model}",
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                    color: _selectedIndex ==
                                                                            index
                                                                        ? Colors
                                                                            .white
                                                                        : Colors
                                                                            .black,
                                                                    fontSize:
                                                                        16,
                                                                    fontWeight:
                                                                        FontWeight
                                                                            .w600),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: Align(
                                                            alignment: Alignment
                                                                .topLeft,
                                                            child: Container(
                                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                                      width:
                                                                          1.0,
                                                                      color: const Color(
                                                                          0xffb8d5f5)),
                                                                  color: _selectedIndex ==
                                                                          index
                                                                      ? Color(AppColors
                                                                          .primaryBlueColor)
                                                                      : Color(AppColors
                                                                          .bgColor),
                                                                  borderRadius:
                                                                      const BorderRadius
                                                                              .all(
                                                                          Radius.circular(
                                                                              5))),
                                                              padding:
                                                                  const EdgeInsets
                                                                      .all(3),
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                "${snapshot.data[index].year}",
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                    color: _selectedIndex ==
                                                                            index
                                                                        ? Colors
                                                                            .white
                                                                        : Color(AppColors
                                                                            .primaryBlueColor),
                                                                    fontSize:
                                                                        10,
                                                                    fontWeight:
                                                                        FontWeight
                                                                            .w500),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                      //onTap: () {},
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ));
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

'''
I am trying to display this horizontal list using the future builder this is working fine in debug mode but not in release mode. In release mode, where the list should display it just displays the grey background color. The future builder container is placed inside a column.
The scroll is working fine when it stops the issue occurs when the list going to display.
I don't know if there is some layout issue or what but working fine in debug mode. How can I figure out the issue in release mode

[image]

Comment: are you calling these data from any api or just the dummy data?

Comment: It is due to render flow error. Please check console while debug the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code
this working in release mode

```
Container(
            //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getContracts,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                           CircularProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                Color(AppColors.progressBarcolor),
                              )
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                            child: const Text('Fatching Vehicles...'),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                  );
                } else {
                  return SizedBox(
                      height: 90,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        //physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        //shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              converages(
                                  snapshot.data[index].coverages);
                              setState(() {
                                _selectedIndex = index;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              width: 220,
                              height: 70,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, left: 20),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: _selectedIndex == index
                                    ? Colors.blue
                                    : Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(15)),
                              ),
    
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: 64,
                                      width: 64,
                                      //margin:
                                      //    const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(
                                                  10)),
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                                "assets/images/car.png"),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 10),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Align(
                                                  alignment: Alignment
                                                      .bottomLeft,
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets
                                                        .all(0),
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      //"${snapshot.data[index].make}  ${snapshot.data[index].model}",
                                                      "test $index",
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: _selectedIndex ==
                                                              index
                                                              ? Colors
                                                              .white
                                                              : Colors
                                                              .black,
                                                          fontSize:
                                                          16,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight
                                                              .w600),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Align(
                                                  alignment: Alignment
                                                      .topLeft,
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        border: Border.all(
                                                            width:
                                                            1.0,
                                                            color: const Color(
                                                                0xffb8d5f5)),
                                                        color: _selectedIndex ==
                                                            index
                                                            ? Colors.blue
                                                            : Colors.red,
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                        const BorderRadius
                                                            .all(
                                                            Radius.circular(
                                                                5))),
                                                    padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets
                                                        .all(3),
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      //"${snapshot.data[index].year}",
                                                      "2022",
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: _selectedIndex ==
                                                              index
                                                              ? Colors
                                                              .white
                                                              : Colors.blue,
                                                          fontSize:
                                                          10,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight
                                                              .w500),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
    
    
                            ),
                           // onTap: () {},
                          );
                        },
                      )
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: It worked, can you please tell me what was the issue?